# HashSet performance Add vs Contains for existing elements

Tags: c#, performance, hashset

For some reason, it seems the `Add` operation on a `HashSet` is slower than the `Contains` operation when the element already exists in the `HashSet`.

Here is proof:

```
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    int size = 10000;
    int iterations = 10000;


    var s = new HashSet<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        s.Add(i);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(watch.Time(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            s.Add(i);
        }
    }, iterations));

    s = new HashSet<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        s.Add(i);
    }

    // outputs: 47,074,764

    Console.WriteLine(watch.Time(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (!s.Contains(i))
                s.Add(i);
        }
    }, iterations));

    // outputs: 41,125,219
```

Why is `Contains` faster than `Add` for already-existing elements?

Note: I'm using this `Stopwatch` extension from another SO question.

```
    public static long Time(this Stopwatch sw, Action action, int iterations) {
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            action();
        }
        sw.Stop();

        return sw.ElapsedTicks;
    }
```

**UPDATE**: Internal testing has revealed that the big performance diff only happens on the x64 version of the .NET framework. With the 32 bit version of the framework Contains seems run at identical speed to add (in fact it appears that the version with the contains runs a percent slower in some test runs) On X64 versions of the framework, the version with the contains seems to run about 15% faster.

Comment: For the 32 bit testing, did you run it on a 32 bit machine, in a virtual machine, or by specifying an x86 target for the compile and running the 32 bit framework under WOW64?  I don't know that it'd make a difference, but it's possible.

Comment: I performed my 32 bit testing in a VM

Comment: Have you tried moving the testing the Contains Add function above the Add and then measuring the time? You will find that the difference is negligible..

Comment: In my test cases after moving the two methods the Add block sometimes runs faster than the Contains Add..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AddIfNotPresent does an additional divide that Contains doesn't perform.  Take a look at the IL for Contains:

```
IL_000a:  call       instance int32 class System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1<!T>::InternalGetHashCode(!0)
  IL_000f:  stloc.0
  IL_0010:  ldarg.0
  IL_0011:  ldfld      int32[] class System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1<!T>::m_buckets
  IL_0016:  ldloc.0
  IL_0017:  ldarg.0
  IL_0018:  ldfld      int32[] class System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1<!T>::m_buckets
  IL_001d:  ldlen
  IL_001e:  conv.i4
  IL_001f:  rem
  IL_0020:  ldelem.i4
  IL_0021:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0022:  sub
  IL_0023:  stloc.1
```

This is computing the bucket location for the hash code.  The result is saved at local memory location 1.

AddIfNotPresent does something similar, but it also saves the computed value at location 2, so that it can insert the item into the hash table at that position if the item doesn't exist.  It does that save because one of the locations is modified later in the loop that goes looking for the item.  Anyway, here's the relevant code for AddIfNotPresent:

```
IL_0011:  call       instance int32 class System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1<!T>::InternalGetHashCode(!0)
  IL_0016:  stloc.0
  IL_0017:  ldloc.0
  IL_0018:  ldarg.0
  IL_0019:  ldfld      int32[] class System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1<!T>::m_buckets
  IL_001e:  ldlen
  IL_001f:  conv.i4
  IL_0020:  rem
  IL_0021:  stloc.1
  IL_0022:  ldarg.0
  IL_0023:  ldfld      int32[] class System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1<!T>::m_buckets
  IL_0028:  ldloc.0
  IL_0029:  ldarg.0
  IL_002a:  ldfld      int32[] class System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1<!T>::m_buckets
  IL_002f:  ldlen
  IL_0030:  conv.i4
  IL_0031:  rem
  IL_0032:  ldelem.i4
  IL_0033:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0034:  sub
  IL_0035:  stloc.2
```

Anyway, I think the extra divide is what's causing Add to take more time than Contains.  At first glance, it looks like that extra divide could be factored out, but I can't say for sure without spending a little more time deciphering the IL.

Comment: An interesting question is why is this so much slower on x64?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, on my machine (Dell Latitude D630, dual-core 2.2 Ghz) I am getting nearly identical results for both tests unless I run the stopwatch against a `null` action before the tests. For example:

I run the tests with the exact code you have given in the question:

```
Without Contains(): 8205794
With Contains():    8207596
```

If I modify the code in this manner:

After:

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
int size = 10000;
int iterations = 10000;
```

Add:

```
watch.Time(null, 0);
```

My results become:

```
Without Contains(): 8019129
With Contains():    8275771
```

This seems to me like something odd is going on inside of the `Stopwatch` that is causing these fluctuations.

Comment: jeez if you cant trust stopwatch who can you trust :) I just repeated all my tests and am getting results consistent with my original, the gap even gets bigger in release mode.

Comment: This could be related to me having an X64 version of the framework, testing in a VM

Comment: Confirmed the issue appears to be X64 related

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you ran your test from Visual Studio which caused the inlining of `AddIfNotPresent` into `Add` to be suppressed, so you're seeing the result of an extra level of indirection in the method calls.

If I compile and run from the command line to remove any VS trickery...

```
> csc /o+ /t:exe Program.cs
> Program.exe
```

...then there is no performance difference.

Sample outputs (representative of a larger number of tests):

```
35036174
35153818

35225763
34862330

35047377
35033323
```

Comment: nope, just ran in release outside of VS and am finding contains to be 15% faster

Comment: One big difference that my machine has is that im running Vista X64, will quickly test in a VM on 32 bit

Comment: Also my machine is Quad Core which may mean something about the way the GC is operating

Comment: I'm on a Vista x86 dual core at the moment.